# How to set-up the sbt-proguard plugin in Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.11, sbt-proguard

I want to use the **sbt-proguard** plugin in my project, but I need to set it up in a *Build.scala* file.

I read the documentation but there is just an example for the *build.sbt* file, which won't work in my case. **I need to know how to configure the plugin for my Build.scala file.**

Here's the link to the repo: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard/blob/master/README.md#example

**FYI**: *I'm using scala.version=2.11.4 and sbt.version=0.13.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: sbt currently recommends [multi-project build.sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html) instead of build.scala.)

Some of the sbt plugins use scripted to test itself, which sets up fake builds under `src/sbt-test`. If you find one it could contain nice samples on how to set up the plugin.

sbt-proguard created a sample called [akka](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard/blob/v0.2.2/src/sbt-test/proguard/akka/project/SampleBuild.scala) supposedly used by Akka project.

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard._

object SampleBuild extends Build {
  import ProguardKeys.{ mergeStrategies, merge, options }
  import ProguardOptions.keepMain
  import ProguardMerge.append

  lazy val proguardAkka = Project(
    id = "proguard-akka",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ proguardSettings ++ Seq(
      scalaVersion := "2.10.1",
      libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.1.2",
      merge in Proguard := true,
      mergeStrategies in Proguard += append("reference.conf"),
      options in Proguard += keepMain("A"),
      options in Proguard += keepMain("B"),
      options in Proguard += "-dontoptimize", // reduce time for proguard
      options in Proguard += ProguardConf.akka
    )
  )
}
object ProguardConf {
  val akka = ....
}
```